# not able see the navigation menu bar on my home page

Tags: magento-1.9

i installed 19.2 version through shared hosting, my home page showing no sign of menu (right or left) I have created category and products and put all the products under the respected category but no luck!!!!

Comment: Have you added information about quantity of products in stock? If not - they might be not displayed. Also check if all the products enabled.

Comment: firstly their is no relation of menu visibility and product.Is it available on other page? like contact us.about us etc.

Answer (score 0):

In admin go to the **CMS > Pages** and find page with **url key** - home. Then go into that page **design** tab and check your **layout** field there. If **1column** layout is there just change it to **2 columns with left bar** or **2 columns with right bar**.

Comment: didnt find the layout filed !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: http://joxi.ru/n2Ye7Kyij9w8j2

Answer (score 0):

It's seem's that you have not create your category under root category.

**Below are steps for create category** :

1. From Magento Admin panel to Catalog→Manage Categories
2. Select "Root" category
3. On top right click "Add Subcategory"
4. Fill in: General Information/Display Settings/Custom Design/Category Products
5. Click "Save Category" button

[For more detail see here.](https://stuntcoders.com/magento-tutorials/magento-catalog/creating-new-category/)

Comment: I followed all five steps  but still not able to see the navigation menu bar on my store home page

Comment: Please accept this answer if it's solve your problem. Thanks :)